# Referencia indefinida `WinMain@16' c++

Tags: c++

Hola el comando es el siguiente:

```
gcc -o main.dll dllmain.o -L/c/Users/Androide/Desktop/colo/pupa/dllmain/ -lSDL -lSDLmain -lmingw32
```

obtengo el error al compilar mi proyecto, el error es el siguiente:

```
> $ gcc -o main.dll dllmain.o
> -L/c/Users/Androide/Desktop/colo/pupa/dllmain/ -lSDL -lSDLmain -lmingw32 C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):
> In function `main':
> C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18:
> undefined reference to `WinMain@16' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1
> exit status
```

Una captura sobre como lo hice:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código de mi dll que estoy compilando:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) void __cdecl HelloWorld()
{
    //Show a message box with the text "Hello World"
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Hello World"), TEXT("In a DLL"), MB_OK);
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    //Different behaviors depending on the reason why DllMain is called
    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            HelloWorld();
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            HelloWorld();
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Parece que linkeando a -LSDL se podía solucionar pero a mi no me funcionó.

Comment: ¿No será que espera encontrar la función `WinMain` como punto de entrada y tú no la has proveído?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para generar una dll com minGW debes usar una sentencia similar a la siguiente:

```
g++ -shared -o main.dll dllmain.o -L/c/Users/Androide/Desktop/colo/pupa/dllmain/ -lSDL -lSDLmain -lmingw32
    ^^^^^^^
```

Fíjate en la parte que te destaco. si no lo haces así no se generará una DLL sino un ejecutable (te recuerdo que la compilación C++ no entiende de extensiones, por lo que decirle a gcc que la salida es `fichero.dll` no hace que el entienda que debe generar una DLL.